# CHMOD crashes mysql

Tags: mysql, chmod

I believe I have a data corruption issue on my server.

This server has been hitting performance issues over the past few days with a specific set of software: gallery2. I've been attempting to fix it through the normal paths, one of which is deleting the software's caches. The script provided to do so crashes mysql when I run it. The deletion of the cache seems to hang on a specific folder, so I tried to chmod it.

Attempting to chmod the directory crashes mysql as well and the terminal reports the following after the crash:

chmod: changing permissions of `entity/1/4/145446.inc': Read-only file system
+ one of these lines for every file in the directory

The directory in question is: 
/var/www/vhosts/autoimagery.com/httpdocs/gallery2data/cache/entity

The command I ran is a simple recursive chmod:
chmod -R 777 entity/

I'm completely lost on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message "read-only filesystem" would indicate some structural issue (i.e. disk, or filesystem corruption) in the underlying filesystem being used.  My suggestion would be to take the system to single user mode, and do a FULL fsck on the disk area.

If this is the root filesystem, you can invoke a full fsck by 'touch /forcefsck' on redhat linux varients (Redhat, Centos, Fedora).  Then doing a reboot.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I just read up on single user mode: http://centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html This is a dedicated machine I have at a remote host. Is this something I have the ability to do via SSH?

Comment: Hey, my host put the server on what they call 'rescuelayer' and ran fsck immediately after my description of the problem. It fixed the issue completely. Thanks for your help! It's probably bad for karma to name the host but they were excellent so here goes: Softlayer. Support was stellar.